# What overhead is associated with a new team site instance?

Tags: team-sites

I have noticed my organization creating new team sites (full, default sites) whenever they need a place for documents. For instance, a team site library will have hundreds of team sites: Team A 2012, Team B Software version 1.2, Team B Software version 1.3.

This is clearly bad organization, but I need some facts to back up my intuition. What kind of overhead is associated with constantly creating new team sites?(file size, database entries, etc.)

Maybe I'm wrong and this is just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be much of an issue in performance terms since its all done with virtual directories and database queries. But the obvious organizational/space issues would be

- Each Team site creates multiple pages and libraries when created. Whatever the default is set to such as Images, Pages, Document Library, etc. Each site would have unneeded clutter.
- Creating team sites can lead to team sub-sites and eventually you end up giant URLs and difficulties
- Harder to find nested content
- Far more chance for abandoned content